# Pantheon not responding permanently just can move the mouse

Tags: release-loki, pantheon

Pantheon not responding to mouse clicks, hover or anything 
Pantheon not responding permanently just can move the mouse

Comment: I feel like this requires clarification, what part of your system are you calling pantheon?

Comment: pantheon is the desktop environment not responding.. But the system still works. For example I can listen to music while the desktop environment not responding

Comment: I've got the exact same situation. Even when logging in the response to keys are slow but after a loong time I'm logged in. I can SSH and also sometimes Alt-Ctrl-F1 in to the computer and there everything works as normal. Seems as the handling of input events is just very very slow...